# Jetpack Compose ModalBottomSheet always showing

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

The `ModalBottomSheet` seems to be showing by default although it should actually be hidden (`rememberModalBottomSheetState` initiates the state with an `initialValue : SheetValue = Hidden`). Clearly missing something here.

```
val bottomSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState()
ModalBottomSheet(
    onDismissRequest = { /*TODO*/ },
    sheetState = bottomSheetState,
    containerColor = Color.White,
) {
    Text(text = "Why am I showing?", color = Color.Black)
}
```

calling `bottomSheetState.hide()` also doesn't seem to have any effect.

Using Jetpack Compose BOM 2023.06.00 but getting the same behaviour on 2023.05.01.

Comment: Is there any condition to show bottom sheet automatically?

Comment: The [official example](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#ModalBottomSheet(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.material3.SheetState,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.WindowInsets,kotlin.Function1)) has a conditional show... Can't say I like this. Somewhat justifies the @ExperimentalMaterial3Api imho.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally figured this out! The new ModalBottomSheet shows conditionally, so something like this should work:

```
val openBottomSheet = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
val bottomSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState()

if (openBottomSheet) {
  ModalBottomSheet(
    onDismissRequest = { openBottomSheet = false },
    sheetState = bottomSheetState,
    containerColor = Color.White,
  ) {
    Text(text = "Why am I showing?", color = Color.Black)
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not required, the bottom has a state to show or hide it.

Comment: @Abhimanyu The show and hide doesn't seem to be enough because if you hide it, the invisible background still catches all clicks and your layouts underneath becomes unusable.

Comment: Thanks @Ashna. Seems to be the same in the [offical example](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#ModalBottomSheet(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.material3.SheetState,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.WindowInsets,kotlin.Function1)). Really not liking this. Will probably fall back to the normal material ModalBottomSheetLayout.

Comment: @OliverMetz Ok. I missed noticing that the question was about `ModalBottomSheet` and not `ModalBottomSheetLayout`.

Comment: This is really confusing! Why having `sheetState.show()` and `hide()` then? I fell into this trap while migrating a M2 app to M3.

Comment: Yeah it's pretty confusing. So basically, the `sheetState.hide()` function is for triggering the hide animation when you want to close it, as opposed to just making it disappear. So you have to do ` `openBottomSheet = false` and `sheetState.hide()` at the same time if you want it to close in response to something

Comment: Extra weird when you find out you must call `openBottomSheet = true` and `sheetState.show()` in exactly this order or it will just skip the animation. :')